# Cancel back to previous commit

Tags: git

I learn git and I confused with this little problem. Here's the storyline

1. I have 3 commits
2. Now the status of my project files is modified (not staging)
3. I accidentaly back to previous commit (commit 2), and my modified project files is overwritten by the previous commit

How I back to point 2 ? And how to prevent the same accident in the future?

Comment: can you specify how you got to commit 2 (hard or soft reset)?

Comment: using `git reflog` shows you the commits you have had checked out, historically

Answer (score 1):

You can `git reset` your branch back to whatever commit you want it to point to. If you don't know what commit this is, find out using `git reflog` to list the ones you have had checked out before.

Answer (score 0):

By giving `git checkout <branch-name>` you would be go top commit of that branch.

```
$ git checkout <branch-name>
```

Or, you can see all working tree history by `git reflog` command

```
$ git reflog                       # copy the commit-hash you want to go
$ git checkout <copy-commmit-hash> # go to a specific commit
$ git checkout -b <branch-name>    # create a new branch from that commit
```